# Hide the back button on navigation bar is iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

want to hide the back button navigation bar, I have tried the below all statements but none of them worked for me

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES]; //1
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem setHidesBackButton:YES]; //2
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;  //3
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES]; //4
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO; //5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see your 5th statement that you have set NO So please change it.It will work fine.

```
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; //5
```